# Iterate thru dict within dict

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

how to fetch value from the dict within dict within a array.

```
dict1 = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22},{'aa': 111, 'bb': 222},{'aa': 1111, 'bb': 2222}]
}
newvalue = []
for k, v in dict1['c'].iteritems():
    newvalue.append(v[0])
    # I want to loop only 1 first time value
    for val in newvalue:
        print val
```

Find the first value from the dict and loop thru
Desired result:
First built the dict1 values
Second loop thru third item "c" and print.

Got error: `list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`

Comment: you have a **list** of dictionaries under the key `'c'`, not a dictionary

Comment: You are getting this error because `dict1['c']` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself, which is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
for inner_dict in dict1['c']: 
    for k, v in inner_dict:
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that error because `dict1['c']` is a list.

Note the square brackets surrounding the dict in:

```
'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22},{'aa': 111, 'bb': 222},{'aa': 1111, 'bb': 2222}]
```

If you are not able to change the content of the list then just call the 0th item of the list like so:

```
for k, v in dict1['c'][0].iteritems():
    newvalue.append(v[0])
    # I want to loop only 1 first time value
    for val in newvalue:
        print val
```

Comment: what I trying to do is built the content as above. Then I would like to iterate thru first item in the "c". then do something. Would you suggest: `'c': {'aa': 11, 'bb': 22},{'aa': 111, 'bb': 222},{'aa': 1111, 'bb': 2222}`

Comment: How to get a value from the dict? 
Will this work? 
newvalue = dict1['c']['aa'].values()

Comment: To get the value from the dict i used .get() method 
newvalue = dict1['c'][0].get("aa")
result will be 11